# Complexity of multiplying 3 matrices

Tags: matrix-multiplication

There are algorithms that speed up matrix multiplication over the naive $n^3$ algorithm. But supposing you have 3 matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$, is there a way to compute $ABC$ that is asymptotically faster than first computing $AB$ and then computing $(AB)C$? Let's assume the matrices are square and dense.

This question was inspired by this post on [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814500/can-you-multiply-3-matrices-simultaneouly).

Answer (score 1):

No. If you can multiply two $n \times n$ matrices in time $O(f(n))$ then you can also multiply three matrices $A,B,C$ in the same asymptotic running time by first computing $M=AB$ and then $MC$.

Conversely, if you can multiply three matrices in time $O(f(n))$ then you can also multiply two matrices in the same asymptotic running time by letting one of the matrices be the identity matrix.

Comment: What _might_ be possible is to calculate (A*B)*C not in twice the time, but maybe 1.5 times the time of a single product. No idea how.